# Implementing from trait and specialization

Tags: rust, traits

According to the [specialization RFC](https://github.com/nox/rust-rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), I should be able to have multiple `impl`s of the same `trait` on a `struct` by specifying one as default.

I have the code:

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]
struct A(u32);

trait Dummy {}

impl<T> From<T> for A
where
    T: Into<u32>,
{
    default fn from(item: T) -> Self {
        A(item.into())
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for A
where
    T: Dummy,
{
    fn from(item: T) -> Self {
        A(2)
    }
}
```

Even though one of the implementations is default, the compiler still tells me that the two are conflicting implementations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second implementation is not a specialization of the first. It's an alternative implementation that conflicts with the first.

Specialization requires that all types matching your second `impl` also match your first `impl`. In other words the bounds of your specialization need to be a strict subset of the bounds of the default implementation. From the RFC:

> This RFC proposes a design for specialization, which permits multiple impl blocks to apply to the same type/trait, so long as one of the blocks is clearly "more specific" than the other.

Changing your trait definition to

```
trait Dummy: Into<u32> {}
```

makes your code compile.

Check out https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md for more details.

Comment: Is there any part in RFC that states about strict subset bounds for specialization ? Could you please link that ?